# Bash regex extract value inside a quotes after a specific string

Tags: regex, bash

I'd like to extract the value of "job" inside a console text taken from curl, it's : `ix90CvhtaWfMhNiIy3RDbr2lJ2pRzGxBqHSiDq5OcI`

```
95 28.2M     0     0   95 27.0M      0  1091k  0:00:26  0:00:25  0:00:01 2910k
100 28.2M    0    52  100 28.2M      1  1108k  0:00:26  0:00:26 --:--:-- 2887k
100 28.2M    0    52  100 28.2M      1  1108k  0:00:26  0:00:26 --:--:-- 2965k
{"job":"ix90CvhtaWfMhNiIy3RDbr2lJ2pRzGxBqHSiDq5OcI"}
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] }
```

I am using this command to extract the value :

```
curl -v --silent 'link-to-consoleText' 2>/dev/null | grep -Eo '("job":\"[^"]*\")' | head -n1 | awk -F' = ' '{ print $1 }'
```

Current regex use : `("job":\"[^"]*\")`, but it extracted: `"job":"ix90CvhtaWfMhNiIy3RDbr2lJ2pRzGxBqHSiDq5OcI"`.

How to extract only the value? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for grep if you are using awk, try this:

```
curl -v --silent 'link-to-consoleText' 2>/dev/null | awk -F'"' '/job/ {print $4}'
```

Answer (score 1):

If supported, using grep `-P` you can use `\K` to clear the match buffer and assert the `"` at the end.

Note that you don't need the capture group and you don't have to escape the double quotes.

```
curl -v --silent 'link-to-consoleText' 2>/dev/null | grep -Po '"job":"\K[^"]*(?=")'
```